# Putting Resharper's ignored errors under version control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-8.0

When I ignore specific errors in "Errors in Solution" window, Resharper remembers this setting.

[image]

I tried to reboot and restart Visual Studio, the ignored errors stayed ignored. Now I wanted to pass the ignored errors list to another programmers in the team by putting some setting file under version control. But I could not find where does Resharper store which errors are ignored.
I have the following versions of SW.

```
Visual Studio 2012 
JetBrains ReSharper 8.2.1 Full Edition
Build 8.2.1000.4556 on 2014-05-19T10:12:38
```

Update:
I removed files in the following folder and the ignored errors reset, all errors became unignored.

```
%AppData%\..\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\
```

So it keeps the ignored errors somewhere in those files. Still I did not see the way to put it under version control.

Answer (score 2):

**Though not related to the exact issue of the original poster, you might have stumbled upon this question looking for the answer below :)**

If you've changed the behavior of an inspection from the glyph like this and saved it to a configuration layer and set it to Do Not Show or something else and then saved it to the Team level:

[image: Configure inspection severity.]
[image]

Then depending on where you set the value, Computer, Solution personal or Solution Team, it's stored in a different settings file.

You can then add the `Solution.sln.DotSettings` file to source control to share these suppression between all team members.

To undo the supression of such warnings, you'll have to venture into the layered options structure of Resharper, which can be a little confusing if you haven't gone in there before.

[image: Manage Options]

Then depending on where it's saved, look under the wrench item for the selected layer:

[image: Edit Layer]

Find the inspection and set it:

[image: Set the inspection]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I did not want to disable a specific error globally. I ignored specific errors only in specific files or places in the files using Resharper's Window "Errors in Solution". I uploaded a screenshot of this window here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsHNjW9WrskWjhZc3UyYkk1d2c/edit?usp=sharing
It appears there is no simple way to put it under version control...

Comment: I don't see another way for the thing you've ran into in order to put these "suppression" in source control either. It seems they're not meant to be used that way. which surprises me. Have you asked over at the Jetbrains Resharper Community?  http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/resharper

Comment: I have not asked there yet

Answer (score 1):

In the toolbar to the solution errors window, there should be an export button. You should be able to export all ignored items to xml or html here.

Comment: It would not export the ignored items, it exports only un-ignored ones. Anyway, exporting to xml or html is not enough to put the ignored items under source control